# How to implement Login system using JSON structure?

Tags: android, json, url, xamarin.forms

I'м trying to iмplement login system by using json...
Model

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Service

```
class LoginService
{
    public static async Task<bool> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = DataURL.USERS + "/api/account/login";

            string stringContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginModel);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                using (var result = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(stringContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")))
                {
                    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        string rawResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, I'm using `MVVM` pattern,

LoginViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel
{

    public Command LoginCommand => new Command(async () =>
    {
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel("username", "password"); // (pokupiti uneto kor. ime i lozinka)

        if (model.CheckInformation())
        {
            bool isSuccess = await LoginService.Login(model);
            if (isSuccess)
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Пријава неуспешна. Неисправно корисничко име или лозинка.");                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Пријава неуспешна. Неисправно корисничко име или лозинка.OK.");
        }
    });
}
```

LoginPage

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

Here you can see what is on the link that I'm using in service:
[URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZRYF.png)
So, my question is what I'm doing wrong and how to get fix, to get StatusCode.OK?

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception?  What exactly is the problem?  Have you checked your serialized json to verify that it matches what the service expects?

Comment: @Jason `result` always get value of Bad request, so service always return false.
About serializing... I'm probablz missing something... That's why I also give you a image...

Comment: so you can't even get it to work using curl?

Comment: @Jason Acctually I don't know how to use curl. :/

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the service?  We can't just guess what the service expects you to send - without more information there is really no way to help you.

Comment: @Jason All wha I have about service is on image. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZRYF.png)
You can see how model looks like...

Comment: Well, that's useless.

Comment: @Jason Hm....How to compare input username and password with usernma and password from model?

Comment: @NitrusBrio Here is an article , may be helpful for you.https://deanilvincent.github.io//2017/05/16/xamarin-forms-simple-login-with-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

Have a try this , need to install **Newtonsoft.Json** NuGet Package:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```